# Manage project in VSTS does not keep the changes

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, devops

As you can see in the picture I have project administrator permission and I added some projects to Project Administrators group.

[image]

Today I created 2 new projects. And VSTS groups stuck to Custom group.

1. I don't know why I have a new group which is called Custom even I don't have it in Security/Groups.
2. I can't change **Custom** to **Project Administrators** and for other users to **Contributor**.
3. After all, I created a Test project and I didn't get any issues.

How can I fix the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Custom` simply means you're a member of one or more groups that are not in the list of:

- Project Administrators
- Project Contributors
- Project Readers
- The project's Default Team

For example, you're a member of a Team (Teams are represented as a security group). Or you're a member of any custom created group within the project. These custom groups are not shown in the *Manage projects* dialogue.

I do not see the behaviour of not being able to change the values, the only reason I can think of is that your user doesn't have permissions to manage permissions in those projects. Have you tried changing the security directly through the project's own Security tab?

Comment: I also tried what you said in the security. I didn’t get a result. Sometimes VSTS has weird behavior. For example I added users to contributors. And then after couple of minutes when I check the contributors again, there is nothing at all. Anyway I downloaded all repos from github and import them by git cli. Now everything is as I expected. But I think I missed something somewhere.